# Check if column value exists before SELECT

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct(year(date_created)) as theYear from content where folder_id = 1 or folder_id = 2 order by theYear desc", myConn);
```

This statement checks folders for any content then sets a drop down list to equal the year.  However, if there is no content in either of those folders the statement bombs out.  This apparently happens each new year when content hasn't been created yet.  The simple answer is to merely create a piece of content, which fixes the problem. I want to make sure it's set up so that nobody has to worry about it in case something goes wrong.  So, is there a way to check if there is a value in that column before it tries to select.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (ISNULL(year(date_created), year(getdate()))) AS theYear
FROM content
WHERE folder_id = 1
    OR folder_id = 2
ORDER BY theYear DESC
```

that didn't seem to work. I also tried the COUNT, but either my syntax was wrong or I was using it incorrectly.

Can anybody let me know where I went wrong and what the proper method would be?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. Don't use it like one.

Comment: how are you assigning to drop-down,cant you check the logic there

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Thanks for the clarification!  This was the code the was there when I got it, and I was unaware that it was improper.

Comment: @TheGameiswar The SQL statement get's passed on as a datasource for the dropdown.  I thought it might be better to check if data existed before applying logic.  Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `UNION` to tack the current year on to the dataset. Since `UNION` removes duplicates it doesn't matter if it already exists in `Content`:

```
SELECT  YEAR(date_created) AS theYear
FROM    Content
WHERE   folder_id IN (1, 2)
UNION
SELECT  YEAR(GETDATE())
ORDER BY theYear DESC;
```

If you only want the current year to appear if there is no data, then you can put and `EXISTS` check in the second query:

```
SELECT  YEAR(date_created) AS theYear
FROM    Content
WHERE   folder_id IN (1, 2)
UNION
SELECT  YEAR(GETDATE())
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Content WHERE folder_id IN (1, 2) )
ORDER BY theYear DESC;
```

Comment: And what if it has dates in date_created, but the current year does not exist in the data? What I understand is that only the current date should appear if there is no data.

Comment: @JotaPardo OK, I think I misunderstood. I have added a `WHERE` clause to the original query to make sure it only appears where is no data.

Comment: @GarethD  Your first statement ended up being the one that worked for me.  It added 2017 to the list and didn't interfere with any of the previous years that should be there.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your updated statement will still apply the where clause preventing the return of any records, NULL or otherwise.

```
select distinct
    (ISNULL(year(date_created), year(getdate()))) as theYear
from content
where folder_id = 1
    or folder_id = 2
order by theYear desc
```

Try changing it to

```
DECLARE @yearTbl TABLE 
(
    date_created DATE
)

INSERT @yearTbl
SELECT date_created
FROM content
WHERE folder_id = 1
    OR folder_id = 2

IF (SELECT count(*) FROM @yearTbl) = 0
    SELECT year(getdate()) AS theYear
ELSE
    SELECT DISTINCT year(date_created) AS theYear
    FROM @yearTbl
    ORDER BY theYear
```

Comment: With your answer I understood better the question. Is it possible to do the same in only one SELECT statement?